# gitlab-7.7.1-omnibus-5.4.1 creating merge request

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-7

Empty lists of branches when choosing Source / Target branch to merge, but branches can be viewed in branches tab

`sudo gitlab-rake gitlab:check`, everything is ok

try to restart gitlab-ctl, nothing changed

Comment: Checked the production.log?

Comment: it's empty. but very strange thing - now I see all branches. I just changed unicorn port to 8000 and nginx port to 8080 and started `gitlab-ctl reconfigure`. everything it's ok now